# How can I dismiss the image picker after didFinishSavingWithError?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

All I want to do is after the alert is shown that the picture was or wasn't saved the picker should be dismissed, but I can't manage to find out how.

I present the image control like this :

```
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

I know i need to dismissmodalviewcontroller, because i do it for the cancel case, but I don't know where to place it so that after the image is saves it exists.

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    }

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    UIAlertView *alert;

    // Unable to save the image  
    if (error)
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                           message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album." 
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    else // All is well
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" 
                                           message:@"Image saved to Photo Album." 
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create the instance of UIImagePickerController locally and in alertview delegate method, simply dismiss it.

Comment: I updated the question. I know how to dismiss it in general, as i am dismissing it for the cancel but I don't know how to dismiss it after the alert is shown.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How can I create the instance locally?

Comment: create UIImagePickerController * imagepicker; in your controller.h and  in alertview delegte [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE]; go here http://zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/

Answer (score 0):

it is depends on how you present imagepickercontroller if you have used peserntmodelviewcontrolleranimated: then use `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`